# Multiprocessing Pause-Restart functionality using `event`

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using a code posted below to enable **pause-restart** functionality for `multiprocessing` Pool.

I would appreciate if you explain me why `event` variable has to be sent as an argument to `setup()` function. Why then a global variable `unpaused` is declared inside of the scope of `setup()` function  and then it is set to be the same as `event` variable:

```
def setup(event):
    global unpaused
    unpaused = event
```

I also would like to know a logistic behind of the following declaration:

```
pool=mp.Pool(2, setup, (event,))
```

The first argument submitted is the number of the CPU cores to be used by Pool. 
The second argument submitted is a function `setup()` which is mentioned above.

Why wouldn't it all be accomplished like:

```
global event
event=mp.Event()
pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
```

And every time we need to pause or to restart a job we would just use:

To pause:

```
event.clear()
```

To restart:

```
event.set()
```

Why would we need a global variable `unpaused`? I don't get it! Please advise.

---

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def myFunct(arg):
    proc=mp.current_process()
    print 'starting:', proc.name, proc.pid,'...\n'
    for i in range(110):
        for n in range(500000):
            pass
    print '\t ...', proc.name, proc.pid, 'completed\n'

def setup(event):
    global unpaused
    unpaused = event

def pauseJob():
    event.clear()

def continueJob():
    event.set()


event=mp.Event()

pool=mp.Pool(2, setup, (event,))
pool.map_async(myFunct, [1,2,3])

event.set()

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: where did you find this code?

Comment: It was suggested here on Stackoverflow. I have asked how to pause/restart Pool. And that is what was suggested.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how `Event` works. But first, I'll cover what `setup` is doing.

The `setup` function is executed in each child process inside the pool as soon as it is started. So, you're setting a global variable called `event` inside each process to be the the same `multiprocessing.Event` object you created in your main process. You end up with each sub-process having a global variable called `event` that's reference to the same `multiprocessing.Event` object. This will allow you to signal your child processes from the main process, just like you want. See this example:

```
import multiprocessing

event = None
def my_setup(event_):
  global event
  event = event_
  print "event is %s in child" % event


if __name__ == "__main__":
    event = multiprocessing.Event()
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(2, my_setup, (event,))
    print "event is %s in parent" % event
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Output:

```
dan@dantop2:~$ ./mult.py 
event is <multiprocessing.synchronize.Event object at 0x7f93cd7a48d0> in child
event is <multiprocessing.synchronize.Event object at 0x7f93cd7a48d0> in child
event is <multiprocessing.synchronize.Event object at 0x7f93cd7a48d0> in parent
```

As you can see, it's the same `event` in the two child processes as well as the parent. Just like you want.

However, passing `event` to setup actually isn't necessary. You can just inherit the `event` instance from the parent process:

```
import multiprocessing

event = None

def my_worker(num):
    print "event is %s in child" % event

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event = multiprocessing.Event()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    pool.map_async(my_worker, [i for i in range(pool._processes)]) # Just call my_worker for every process in the pool.

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print "event is %s in parent" % event
```

Output:

```
dan@dantop2:~$ ./mult.py 
event is <multiprocessing.synchronize.Event object at 0x7fea3b1dc8d0> in child
event is <multiprocessing.synchronize.Event object at 0x7fea3b1dc8d0> in child
event is <multiprocessing.synchronize.Event object at 0x7fea3b1dc8d0> in parent
```

This is a lot simpler, and is the preferred way to pass a semaphore between parent and child. In fact, if you were to try to pass the `event` directly to a worker function, you'd get an error:

```
RuntimeError: Semaphore objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

Now, back to how you're misunderstanding the way `Event` works. `Event` is meant to be used like this:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def event_func(num):
    print '\t%r is waiting' % multiprocessing.current_process()
    event.wait()
    print '\t%r has woken up' % multiprocessing.current_process()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event = multiprocessing.Event()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    a = pool.map_async(event_func, [i for i in range(pool._processes)])

    print 'main is sleeping'
    time.sleep(2)

    print 'main is setting event'
    event.set()

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Output:

```
main is sleeping
    <Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)> is waiting
    <Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)> is waiting
    <Process(PoolWorker-4, started daemon)> is waiting
    <Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)> is waiting
main is setting event
    <Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)> has woken up
    <Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)> has woken up
    <Process(PoolWorker-4, started daemon)> has woken up
    <Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)> has woken up
```

As you can see, the child processes need to explicitly call `event.wait()` for them to be paused. They get unpaused when `event.set` is called in the main process. Right now none of your workers are calling `event.wait`, so none of them can ever be paused. I suggest you take a look at the docs for [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Event), which `multiprocessing.Event` replicates.

Comment: I know it isn't SO policy, but Thanks! Great informative answer with appreciated extra background.

Comment: hugely helpful!

Comment: NOTE:  On my system (macOSX-10.13.6, python-3.7.6, eclipse-4.11.0), this solution will NOT work if your start process is "spawn": i.e. multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn", force=True).   (The resulting "failure" is interesting in that there is no error generated, however, the code just stops at the line:  event.wait() inside event_func().)  This is important because "spawn" is the default start_method for python 3.8 on MacOSX.

Comment: Also NOTE: there are significant differences in the above code if you use "pool.map()" (which will throw an error message if start_method is "spawn") instead of "pool.map_async()" (where no error is generated but code fails).  Eventually, I abandoned "pool" and used multiple separate processes for a much cleaner execution (like: "multiprocessing.Process(target=runGUIthread_v2, args=(myEvent,yearParams,))").